# Breaking down a haskell function

Tags: haskell

I'm reading Real world haskell book again and it's making more sense. I've come accross this function and wanted to know if my interpretation of what it's doing is correct. The function is

```
oddList :: [Int] -> [Int]

oddList (x:xs) | odd x     = x : oddList xs
               | otherwise = oddList xs
oddList _                  = []
```

I've read that as

Define the function oddList which accepts a list of ints and returns a list of ints.

Pattern matching: when the parameter is a list.

Take the first item, binding it to x, leaving the remainder elements in xs.

If x is an odd number prepend x to the result of applying oddList to the remaining elements xs and return that result. Repeat...

When x isn't odd, just return the result of applying oddList to xs

In all other cases return an empty list.

1) Is that a suitable/correct way of reading that?

2) Even though I think I understand it, I'm not convinced I've got the (x:xs) bit down. How should that be read, what's it actually doing?

3) Is the |...| otherwise syntax similar/same as the case expr of syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it right.

The `(x:xs)` parts says: If the list contains at least one element, bind the first element to `x`, and the rest of the list to `xs`

The code could also be written as

```
oddList :: [Int] -> [Int]
oddList (x:xs) = case (odd x) of
                   True  -> x : oddList xs
                   False -> oddList xs
oddList _ = []
```

In this specific case, the guard (`|`) is just a prettier way to write that down. Note that `otherwise` is just a synonym for `True` , which usually makes the code easier to read.

---

What @DanielWagner is pointing out, is we in some cases, the use of guards allow for some more complex behavior.

Consider this function (which is only relevant for illustrating the principle)

```
funnyList :: [Int] -> [Int]
funnyList (x1:x2:xs)
    | even x1 && even x2 = x1 : funnyList xs
    | odd x1 && odd x2   = x2 : funnyList xs
funnyList (x:xs)
    | odd x     = x : funnyList xs
funnyList _ = []
```

This function will go though these clauses until one of them is true:

- If there are at least two elements (`x1` and `x2`) **and** they are both even, then the result is:

  - adding the first element (`x1`) to the result of processing the rest of the list (not including `x1` or `x2`)
- If there are at least one element in the list (`x`), **and** it is odd, then the result is:

  - adding the first element (`x`) to the result of processing the rest of the list (not including `x`)
- No matter what the list looks like, the result is:

  - an empty list `[]`

thus `funnyList [1,3,4,5] == [1,3]` and `funnyList [1,2,4,5,6] == [1,2,5]`

---

You should also checkout the free online book [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)

Comment: Actually, guards are not *quite* the same as moving the guarded expression to a `case` on the right-hand side of an equality. Unlike a `case` on the right-hand side, guards do not commit unless they match.

Comment: @RasmusWriedtLarsen thanks, helps to have it confirmed. I've also got Learn you as Haskell (refer to it sometimes) but I've found Real world haskell is more for me. It gets me doing more and I learn better that way.

Comment: @DanielWagner true, I have added an example to illustrate your point.

Answer (score 3):

1 I'd make only 2 changes to your description:

- when the parameter is a *nonempty* list.
- f x is an odd number prepend x to the result of applying oddList to the remaining elements xs and return that result. [delete "Repeat...""]

Note that for the "_", "In all other cases" actually means "When the argument is an empty list", since that is the only other case.

2 The `(x:xs)` is a pattern that introduces two variables. The pattern matches non empty lists and binds the `x` variable to the first item (head) of the list and binds `xs` to the remainder (tail) of the list.

3 Yes. An equivalent way to write the same function is

oddList :: [Int] -> [Int]

```
 oddList ys = case ys of { (x:xs) | odd x     -> x : oddList xs ;
                           (x:xs) | otherwise -> oddList xs ;
                           _                  -> [] }
```

Note that `otherwise` is just the same as `True`, so `| otherwise` could be omitted here.

Answer (score 2):

You've correctly understood what it does on the low level.

However, with some experience you should be able to interpret it in the "big picture" right away: when you have two cases `(x:xs)` and `_`, and `xs` only turns up again as an argument to the function again, it means this is a *list consumer*. In fact, such a function is always equivalent to a `foldr`. Your function has the form

```
oddList' (x:xs) = g x $ oddList' xs
oddList' [] = q
```

with

```
g :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
g x qs | odd x      = x : qs
       | otherwise  = qs
q = [] :: [Int]
```

The definition can thus be compacted to `oddList' = foldr g q`.

While you may right now not be more comfortable with a fold than with explicit recursion, it's actually much simpler to read once you've seen it a few times.

Actually of course, the example can be done even simpler: `oddList'' = filter odd`.

Answer (score 1):

Read `(x:xs)` as: *a list that was constructed with an expression of the form `(x:xs)`*

And then, make sure you understand that every non-empty list **must** have been constructed with the (:) constructor.

This is apparent when you consider that the list type has just 2 constructors: [] construct the empty list, while (a:xs) constructs the list whose head is a and whose tail is xs.

You need also to mentally de-sugar expressions like

```
[a,b,c] = a : b : c : []
```

and

```
"foo" = 'f' : 'o' : 'o' : []
```

This syntactic sugar is the only difference between lists and other types like Maybe, Either or your own types. For example, when you write

```
foo (Just x) = ....
foo Nothing  = .....
```

we are also considering the two base cases for Maybe:

1. it has been constructed with `Just`
2. it has been constructed with `Nothing`